# Vaadin Valo page will not scroll

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin-valo-theme

I'm creating a new Vaadin theme based on the native Valo theme. After the upgrade to Vaadin 7.3 Valo (done by someone else) the page content won't scroll anymore. All of the other elements on the page where overflow property is applied, work fine except the whole page itself.

I know I could apply this

```
      .v-ui > .v-widget {
      overflow: visible;
      }
```

which would be an 'ok' solution.
But it's not what would normally be seen after an upgrade. What could be causing such behavior? At the moment no additional styles are in use, only the native Valo.

Comment: It works for me, either in 7.4.8 or in the latest build 7.5.0.

Comment: You should take a look to my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028870/how-can-i-make-a-verticallayout-scrollable-using-vaadin