# How can I make a VerticalLayout scrollable using vaadin?

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a Components which exists as a common layout for all my pages. The layout of this component is as follows (made using paint so please sorry :p):

[image: layout]

Right arrows mean that this layout is a HorizontalLayout and down arrows VerticalLayout.

I'm really interested in making bodyContent layout SCROLLABLE. Within this layout I usually introduce lots of UI components (more layouts, text fields, forms, grids...) and sometimes components aren't shown due to the lack of vertical space and the absence of vertical scroll. So is there any way to make bodyContent scrollable (using SCSS/CSS or any other way)?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I've solved this thanks to [@JaneVi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556026/vaadin-valo-page-will-not-scroll):

```
.v-ui > .v-widget {
   overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `Panel` within which you can put your bodyContent(vertical layout) using `setContent()` and can have scroll bars when height of your layout exceeds the panel's height.

Comment: I've been told here to set the vertical layout height to undefined https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/10383018

Comment: And works like magic! Refer to my main post to see how I achieved this :)